# MVC Making database queries in multiple controllers

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

If I have **one** controller that handles database queries, I have no problems adding/removing to my database

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }

    protected ApplicationDbContext db { get; set; }

    public string GetUserId()
    {
        return User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }

    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
        this.db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        UserManager = userManager;            
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Manage()
    {            
        // Populate our view
        ManageViewModel model = new ManageViewModel();

        // Get our user id and then find what cars our user has
        string id = GetUserId();

        // User Cars
        model.UserMajors = (from m in db.UserHasCars where m.ApplicationUserId == id select m.Car).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Manage(FormCollection form)
    {
        // snip
        var queryCars = (from m in db.UserHasCars where m.ApplicationUserId == id select m).ToList();

        foreach (var record in queryCars)
        {
             db.UserHasCars.Remove(record);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        // snip
    }
```

Everything goes smoothly, as expected. But the action method "Manage" fits better in another controller rather than Account. I decide to move both of these actions into my Setting controller, and keep everything else the same - same constructor, same properties. In my Setting controller, when I post to Manage, it horrifically breaks on `db.UserHasCars.Remove(record)` spitting out this:

`"A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion."`

I'd like to move actions that are better suited for other controllers, but with this error, I might have to keep all my database calls in a single controller. How can I move my actions into another controller?

Comment: This is why you should use IOC and a per request lifestyle.  You will get the same DB context in all controllers.  Doing a new on the DB Context in every controller is not the best idea unless you are just doing readonly data.

Comment: You've got two contexts operating at the same time. You should clean that up first.

Comment: Most business logic really belongs in a business library that is outside of the controllers. The purpose of the controller is to package the view model into the view and then return it. Not perform business logic.

Comment: IOC? I've heard about using that, I'll take it and run with it - see how far it goes